# How to unpack the value (a list) of every item in a RDD in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a RDD and every item is of the form

```
(key, [ele1, ele2, ele3, ..., elen])
```

Every item is a key value pair and the value is a list of elements.

I want to unpack the list such that I can create a new RDD with every item containing one element as follows:

```
(key, ele1)
(key, ele2)
(key, ele3)
.
.
.
(key, ele4)
```

How can I do this in PySpark?

I tried doing

```
RDD.flatmap(lambda line: line[1])
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such as this? I used `str` elements for simplicity.

```
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([('key', ['ele1', 'ele2'])])
>>> rdd.flatMap(lambda data: [(data[0], x) for x in data[1]]).collect()
[('key', 'ele1'), ('key', 'ele2')]
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it doesn't work. It throws an error "AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'flatmap'"

Comment: @zero323 since you edited my answer to be rdd specific, can you resolve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It is a typo - `flatmap` != `flatMap`.